# Generate random value, getting relational text from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called RandomPassword, in SQL Server, which has these fields

| ID | PasswordText | PasswordEncrypt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | $2a$04 |
| 2 | Bye | 5345$45 |

I want to add this values once a customer is created, to start with a basic password for them, which they have to change at the first login.

So, on the table RandomPassword I have 200 rows, and the idea is that for every new customer created on the table of customers, a random password is generated.

I'm battling with the fact that I don't know how to generate a random number that repeats twice, because I need to update two fields in the customers table.

So, I want to update customers table with a random ID, and his relational value from RandomPassword. I don't know if there's any way to do it via update, I've made it in a cursor, but will be better on doing it in one transaction.

At the end I want to update two columns of the same row, by given a random value from RandomPassword, like this.

| IDCustomer | Name | PasswordID | PasswordEncrypt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35 | Peter | null | null |
| 47 | Parker | null | null |

to

| IDCustomer | Name | PasswordID | PasswordEncrypt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35 | Peter | 1 | $2a$04 |
| 47 | Parker | 2 | 5345$45 |

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show us the SQL you currently have.

Comment: I would make the case that having a table of 200 "random" passwords is a design problem. Why not simply generate a random string of characters that is x number of characters long? Then you don't have to worry about which random password was assigned. Not to mention that you have some other challenges here as it sounds like your passwords are stored in clear text. They should be salted and hashed.

Comment: Agreed, why would you do this? Just generate a random password on the fly. Perhaps `CONVERT(varchar(16), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8), 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two random numbers.  You can update both fields at once.

```
DECLARE @random INT
SET @random = (SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*200)+1)

UPDATE Customers
SET PasswordID = @random, PasswordEncryp = 
    (SELECT PasswrodEncrypt 
    FROM RandomPassword
    WHERE PasswordID = @random
    )
WHERE IDCustomer = /* whatever customer you want */
```